# Are TPM's locality 2 registers accessible from SRTM?

Tags: virtualization, tpm

We are designing a solution that uses virtualization and TPM. Our intention is to utilize its locality to control access to certain PCRs. The question is whether it make sense to read, say, the status register in locality 2 from the statically boot hypervisor or guest OS? If I understand it correctly, the hypervisor and the guest OS are in locality 0, and there seems to be nothing that stops them from reading the register.

Comment: Does my answer satisfy you? If not I might misunderstood you. If this is the case feel free to leave comments and/or edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a TPM 1.2.

I'm not sure whether I get your question. There is just *one* set of PCRs, most likely 24 in your case. All of them are readable all the time. There are no restrictions for reading a PCR.